# How to show cross of two mysql tables with counts of values?

Tags: mysql

I have two separate tables in MySQL with a foreign key between them. A `households` table and a `mothers` table.

`households` table looks like this.

```
hh_id    rural    urban    area
0001     1        0        12
0002     1        0        15
0003     0        1        12
0004     1        0        15
```

`mothers` table looks like this

```
m_id    hh_id    lit    birth_assissted
0001    0002     1      1
0002    0003     0      0
0003    0001     0      1
```

There are many more field in both tables.

**How can I get data in following form about mothers?**

```
        birth_asssited    lit
urban   1                 2
rural   2                 2
```

This is a cross between two tables that shows count of urban mother who were birth assisted and were literate. Similarly, count of urban mothers who were birth assisted and literate.

The columns of household tables are being shown as rows while columns of mothers tables are shown as columns and all the values are counts.

Comment: I don't understand how the result set relates to the data set

Answer (score 0):

if the rural and urban columns are gauranteed to be mutual exclusive you could do it like this

```
select 
    case when hh.rural = 1 then 'rural' else 'urban' end,
    sum(m.birth_assisted),
    sum(m.lit) 
from households hh left join mothers m on  hh.hh_id = m.hh_id
group by hh.rural
```

I normally work with MSSql so  I am not a 100% sure about this be totally valid mysql syntax, but it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `UNION ALL` operation in order to unpivot the table according to either `urban` or `rural`, then apply aggregation to get the expected result:

```
SELECT type, SUM(lit) AS lit, SUM(birth_assisted) AS birth_assisted
FROM (
   SELECT 'rural' AS type, lit, birth_assisted
   FROM households AS h
   JOIN mothers AS m ON h.hh_id = m.hh_id
   WHERE rural = 1

   UNION ALL

   SELECT 'urban' AS type, lit, birth_assisted
   FROM households AS h
   JOIN mothers AS m ON h.hh_id = m.hh_id
   WHERE urban = 1) AS t
GROUP BY type
```

Comment: What if theres only one column for urban/rural and 1 and 2 are used to show if the household is urban or rural? Similarly, if the education level is also checked and a column `edu` is used with values from 1 to 5 to show level of education.

Comment: @user3431803 I tried to answer to the question posted. If you have a different requirement then you should either clearly state it in the OP or try writing a new post.

Comment: Okay I will make a new post. Thanks.